# Error occurred when creating react application using vs code, How to solve this?

Tags: reactjs, npm

npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/react-scripts
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 is a package version that is forbidden by your security policy.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Alien\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2022-05-21T11_17_48_470Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting mern-excercise-tracker/ from C:\Users\Alien\Desktop\React\project
Done.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are new to React so go through this and configure your application first
before https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/install-react-with-create-react-app/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).